# Way to get field value in JavaScript (compatible with all input types)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Knowing just the field name is there any way to get the value in such a way that is compatible with text, textarea and radio button.

Either using native javascript or the jQuery library

I can use `$("input[name='field1']").val()` but it doesn't work with radio buttons or i can use `$("input[name='field1']:checked").val()` but it only works with radio buttons. I know I can add logic that tries to determine the field type but starts getting complicated as you accommodate more types of fields.

Below is a more concrete example of what I am trying to do:

```
<form>
    <label><input type="radio" name="field1" value="a" /> a</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="field1" value="b" /> b</label>
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
    <button type="button">Test</button>
</form>

<script>
    getFieldValue = function(name1) {
        return $("input[name='" + name1 + "']").val(); //doesn't work with radio buttons
    }
    $('button').click( function() {
        alert(getFieldValue('field1'));
    });
</script>
```

*Update 5/26/2017*
Ended up using the jQuery serializeArray function. Below is my code in case anyone is curious (https://jsfiddle.net/t6p8sqLu/2/)

```
var formdata = $("form").serializeArray();
function getFieldValue(name) {
    var result = [];
    for (var x in formdata) {
        if (formdata[x].name === name) {
            result.push(formdata[x].value);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `$("name='google'").val()`?

Comment: Why would you need to?

Comment: @Alon - Your answer doesn't work with radio buttons

Comment: @KevinB, I am trying to automate filling in an autocomplete box while referencing other fields

Comment: @webwake So how about showing us your html and what you tried so far?

Comment: Then the answer is... create a function that does this for you.

Comment: @KevinB was hoping there is a function that is already built in that  accommodates the different types of inputs. There very well might not be in which case I guess that would be something that I would have to do.

Comment: There probably is one, somewhere on the web. Just not within the built-in toolkit or jquery.

Comment: @AlonEitan I added some examples of what I have tried

Comment: @webwake So what about `$("name='field1':not(:radio),[name='field1']:radio:checked").val()`?

Comment: @AlonEitan slight correction to your code `$("[name='field2']:not(:radio),[name='field2']:radio:checked").val()` that works. I guess was looking for a more elegant solution (but guess there isn't one).

Comment: @webwake Unfortunately it seems there isn't because of the nature of radio buttons. Of course if it was also for checkbox then you would also have to use `each` in order to iterate over the checked boxes

Comment: @AlonEitan your point of check boxes is also an issue as well so I ended up finding another solution and posted it as an answer (it seems cleaner to me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a `form with name` and all input fields with `name`, then you might want to use `jQuery('form[name="xyz"]').serializeArray()`.

[Jquery Serialize Array](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

[Jquery Serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)   *// always returns string*

Or you can always use jquery pseudo selector

```js
$(":input").each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('type') === 'radio' && !$(this).prop('checked')) {
    return;
  }
  console.log($(this).attr('name'), $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  input text:
  <input type="text" name="name1" value="Name" /><br/>
  Checkbox
  <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="yes" checked /> Yes
  <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="all" checked /> Yes to all<br/>
  Radio
  <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="yes" checked />
  <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="no" /><br/>
  Textarea
  <textarea name="textarea">Textarea</textarea><br/>
  Select
  <select name="select1">
    <option value="dummy" selected>Dummy</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: the pseudo selector doesn't work with radio buttons, the serialize just returns a string. It looks like the Serialize Array might work with some filtering.

Comment: Updated. Yes serialize will give string

Comment: I ended up using this technique as it was the only that was browser independent.

Comment: For more clarification, I ended up using the jquery('form').serializeArray() technique as it was the only that was browser independent and control independent sample in fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/t6p8sqLu/1/

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of digging found the native FormData construct works nicely and can accommodate all input types

Ultimately it is the following code

```
(new FormData(document.querySelector("form"))).getAll(name).join(',');
```

Full Test Code

```
<form>
  <div>
    <label><input type="radio" name="field1" value="a" /> a</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="field1" value="b" /> b</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea name="field3"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="field4" value="x" /> x
    <input type="checkbox" name="field4" value="y" /> y
  </div>
  <button type="button">Test</button>

</form>
<script>

  function getFieldValue(name) {
    return (new FormData(document.querySelector("form"))).getAll(name).join(',');
  }

  $('button').click( function() {
    alert('field1:' + getFieldValue('field1'));
    alert('field2:' + getFieldValue('field2'));
    alert('field3:' + getFieldValue('field3'));
    alert('field4:' + getFieldValue('field4'));
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Nice and neat solution.  One should be sure that the browser supports getAll().  Check for compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/getAll

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the OP's question as it pertains to JavaScript is that unless you're able to use a browser compatible with the FormData object and its methods, the answer is then likely probably not unless you can iterate through FormData using the "for(var p of iterable)" syntax.

So, here's one way to automate retrieving the values of a form containing traditional inputs with JavaScript. Note, the custom function showNameValue() works with all the inputs the same way.  But, the event listener treats controls differently since the radio buttons and checkboxes need to be inspected for having been checked while the text input and textarea need to be evaluated for whether there is any discernible content.

```
function showNameValue(obj) {
  var arr = [ obj.name, obj.value ];
  console.log( arr.join(": ") );
}

var d = document;
var btn = d.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
var e = d.forms[0].elements;
var f = null; // field

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  for (var i = 0, max = e.length; i < max; i++) {
    f = e[i];

    switch (f.type) {
      case "radio":
        if (f.checked) {
          showNameValue(f);
        }
        break;
      case "checkbox":
        if (f.checked) {
          showNameValue(f);
        }
        break;
      case "textarea":
        if (f.value = f.value.trim()) {
          showNameValue(f);
        }
        break;
      case "text":
        if (f.value = f.value.trim()) {
          showNameValue(f);
        }
        break;
    }
  } //end for
}); // end event listener
```

See [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbQrOM)

Note, though the textarea HTML tag does not have an explicit type attribute, the DOM Textarea object (see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_textarea.asp)) possesses such a property, so JavaScript can detect its value.  Also, trimming  text and textarea values matters because empty space may precede or follow these values due to space, newline or tab characters.

Answer (score -1):

I've been using this function for years, and it works

```js
function getValueForm(id, return_num){
    var value = "";
    
    if($("#"+id).is(":checkbox")){
        value = ($("#"+id).is(':checked'))?"1":"";
    }else{
        value = $("#"+id).val();
    }

    if(value === null){
        value = "";
    }

    return_num = (return_num === undefined)?false:return_num;

    if(return_num){
        if(value === ""){
            value = 0;
        }else{
            value = parseFloat(value);
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Please consider adding an explanation to make it a quality answer. Code-only answers are discouraged. Most answers receive votes over time as future visitors learn something insightful from your explanation that they can apply to solve their own coding issues.